# How can I export a notebook into multimarkdown?

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, output-formatting

[Mulitmarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) (.md filetype) is a very nice document format that supports rendering mathematical expressions like latex or mathml, rendering syntax highlighted code blocks for any language, as well as all the standard things like images, tables, columns...

I'd like to know how can I convert a notebook into this format.

This isn't supported yet, but has anyone written a package or tool for this?

Comment: There's a duplicate for this somewhere which you might want to try to find.  The title might mention posting to SE from Mma directly instead of markdown.  Sorry, I don't have time to find it now.

Comment: what should be changed in your topic about exportig notebook to markdown so it fits that?